# Obtener ortogonalización por Gram-Schmidt en Java

Tags: java, matrices

Tengo que obtener la solución A=QR de una matriz en Java por medio de la ortogonalización de Gram-Schmidt. Estoy trabajando con las columnas de la matriz como double[] y las guardo en un ArrayList, lo que estoy haciendo es calculando el Q para hacer el resto pero tengo el problema que el código al entrar en el primer ciclo for, me cambia el valor del arregloFinal y pone los elementos del primer vector en 0. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
/*
Se debe hacer Uk = (Vk - (Uk-1*Vk)*Uk-1 - ... - (U1*Vk)*Uk1)/||Uk|| 
||Uk|| = Length de Uk

Los vectores U pertenecen al arreglo final y los V pertenecen al arreglo entrante
*/
public ArrayList< double[] > gramSchmidt(ArrayList< double[] > arreglo)
{
    ArrayList< double[] > arregloFinal = new ArrayList<>();

    //Ajusto el primer vector del arreglo final porque nunca varía, siempre es el primero del arreglo entrante dividido entre su length
    arregloFinal.add(multiplicarEscalarPorVector(1/(calcularLengthVector(arreglo.get(0))), arreglo.get(0)));
    //Aqui se pone el primer vector del arregloFinal en 0 todo. Lo sé porque imprimí todo en consola
    for(int i=1; i<arreglo.size(); i++)
    {
        double[] vectorNuevo = restarVectores(arreglo.get(i), proyeccion(arregloFinal.get(i-1),arreglo.get(i)));
        for(int e=i-1;e>0;e--)
        {
            vectorNuevo = restarVectores(vectorNuevo, proyeccion(arregloFinal.get(e-1),arreglo.get(e)));
        }
        vectorNuevo = multiplicarEscalarPorVector(1/(calcularLengthVector(vectorNuevo)), vectorNuevo);
        arregloFinal.add(vectorNuevo);
    }
    return arregloFinal;
}

//Obtiene el (Uk-1*Vk)*Uk-1
public double[] proyeccion(double[] arreglo1, double[] arreglo2)
{
    double resultadoProductoPunto = productoPunto(arreglo1,arreglo2);
    double[] vectorFinal = multiplicarEscalarPorVector(resultadoProductoPunto, arreglo1);
    return vectorFinal;
}

//Para hacer el Uk-1*Vk
public double productoPunto(double[] vector1, double[] vector2)
{
    double resultado = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<vector1.length; i++)
    {
        resultado+=vector1[i]*vector2[i];
    }
    return resultado;
}

public double[] multiplicarEscalarPorVector(double escalar, double[] vector)
{
    double[] vectorNuevo = vector;
    for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
    {
        vectorNuevo[i] = escalar*vector[i];
    }
    return vectorNuevo;
}

public double[] restarVectores(double[] vector1, double[] vector2)
{
    double[] vectorFinal = vector1;
    for(int i=0; i<vector1.length; i++)
    {
        vectorFinal[i] = vector1[i] - vector2[i];
    }
    return vectorFinal;
}

//Calcula la distancia euclideana de un vector
public double calcularLengthVector(double[] vector)
{
    double resultado = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
    {
        resultado +=Math.pow(vector[i], 2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No conozco la ortogonalización de Gram-Schmidt. 
En el código que colocas no pones como estas invocando tu función gramSchmidt(). Dando algunos valores para invocar a la función:

```
   public static void main( String[] args)
   {
      Main main = new Main();

      ArrayList<double[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
      lista.add( new double[]{10,11});
      lista.add( new double[]{12,13});
      main.gramSchmidt(lista);

   }
```

No aprecio que se vayan a 0 los valores del indice 0 de arregloFinal. Aunque imprimiendo el arreglo veo que si están cambiando los valores del elemento 0.
Esto lo miro en la siguiente salida:

```
El arreglo con primer elemento es: 

0.6726727939963124 0.7399400733959437 
Luego de agregar valores: 

11.900452488687781 13.09049773755656 
0.7399400733959496 -0.6726727939963059
```

Producto de haber modificado los la función gramSchmidt() con impresiones de pantalla. Y generando una función como muestro a continuación.

```
   public ArrayList< double[]> gramSchmidt(ArrayList< double[]> arreglo) {
      ArrayList< double[]> arregloFinal = new ArrayList<>();

      //Ajusto el primer vector del arreglo final porque nunca varía, siempre es el primero del arreglo entrante dividido entre su length
      arregloFinal.add(multiplicarEscalarPorVector(1 / (calcularLengthVector(arreglo.get(0))), arreglo.get(0)));

      System.out.println("El arreglo con primer elemento es: ");
      imprime(arregloFinal);

      //Aqui se pone el primer vector del arregloFinal en 0 todo. Lo sé porque imprimí todo en consola
      for (int i = 1; i < arreglo.size(); i++) {
     double[] vectorNuevo = restarVectores(arreglo.get(i), proyeccion(arregloFinal.get(i - 1), arreglo.get(i)));
     for (int e = i - 1; e > 0; e--) {
        vectorNuevo = restarVectores(vectorNuevo, proyeccion(arregloFinal.get(e - 1), arreglo.get(e)));
     }
     vectorNuevo = multiplicarEscalarPorVector(1 / (calcularLengthVector(vectorNuevo)), vectorNuevo);
     arregloFinal.add(vectorNuevo);

     System.out.println("Luego de agregar valores: ");
     imprime(arregloFinal);
      }
      return arregloFinal;
   }

   public void imprime(ArrayList<double[]> arreglo)
   {
      System.out.println();
      for( double[] arre : arreglo)
      {

         for( double val : arre)
         {
            System.out.print( val+" ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

Tienes un comentario en la función  **gramSchmidt**() que indica:

```
//Ajusto el primer vector del arreglo final porque nunca varía, siempre es el primero del arreglo entrante dividido entre su length
```

Lo que indica que esa primer asignación debe respetarse. Como se aprecia en la impresión de pantalla la asignación no se esta respetando. ¿Por qué?

Bueno es que las funciones **multiplicarEscalarPorVector** y **restarVectores** están afectando a los elementos de **arregloFinal** indirectamente.

En **multiplicarEscalarPorVector** se esta haciendo:

```
double[] vectorNuevo = vector;
```

Donde **vector** es parámetro de **multiplicarEscalarPorVector**. Al tratarse de un arreglo de doubles no se esta generando una copia del arreglo que se envía por parámetro, si no que se esta pasando tal cual la referencia. Esto provoca que **vectorNuevo** apunte a la misma dirección de memoria que el elemento de **arregloFinal** que se envió por parámetro.

Imagino que lo que deseabas es que **vectorNuevo** fuera un nuevo arreglo con los mismos valores que **vector**.

Para hacer eso hay que solicitar memoria para **vectorNuevo** usando el operador **new** e invocar a **System.arrayCopy** para generar la copia de valores.

Se aprecia el mismo defecto en el método  **restarValores**.

La modificación a ambos métodos resultaría en lo siguiente:

```
   public double[] multiplicarEscalarPorVector(double escalar, double[] vector) {
      double[] vectorNuevo = new double[vector.length];
      System.arraycopy(vector, 0, vectorNuevo, 0, vector.length);

      for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
         vectorNuevo[i] = escalar * vector[i];
      }
      return vectorNuevo;
   }

   public double[] restarVectores(double[] vector1, double[] vector2) {
      double[] vectorFinal = new double[vector1.length];
      System.arraycopy(vectorFinal, 0, vector1, 0, vector1.length);

      for (int i = 0; i < vector1.length; i++) {
     vectorFinal[i] = vector1[i] - vector2[i];
      }
      return vectorFinal;
   }
```

Con lo que al ejecutar con los mismos datos de entrada obtenemos:

```
El arreglo con primer elemento es: 

0.6726727939963124 0.7399400733959437 
Luego de agregar valores: 

0.6726727939963124 0.7399400733959437 
-0.6726727939963125 -0.7399400733959438
```

Respetándose ahora los elementos del indice 0 de **arregloFinal**.
Por la fecha de la publicación de la pregunta es posible que en estos momentos ya no te sea de tanta utilidad la respuesta, sin embargo de estar dando solución al problema sería un buen ejemplo de la máxima que dice: En Java cuando se pasa por parámetro un arreglo este siempre se pasa por referencia y no por valor aunque este dentro de otro objeto o sea elemento de una lista, un mapa u otro tipo de dato.